# Как в приложении реализовать диалог "Пауза"?

Tags: java, android

Есть layout с вьюхами и с одной кнопочкой OK. Цель, сделать из этой кнопочки окно сообщения - простой MessageBox. С основного кода должен вызыватся этот layout.
Если я пишу просто:

```
dialogLayout.setVisible(View.VISIBLE)
```

то этот поток, который вызывает наше окно сообщений, не ждет ответа (нажатия кнопочки ОК) пользователем, а продолжает свой поток гнать дальше.
Как сделать так, чтобы после `dialogLayout.setVisible(View.VISIBLE)` приложение ждало ответа от этого `dialogLayout` и потом только продолжило?

Отмечу, что при нажатии на OK на `dialogLayout`, это вызванное окошко должно просто закрыться.

Comment: А чем вас AlertDialog\DialogFragment не устраивает?

Comment: А можно ли его дизайн подогнать под свои нужды? Можно ли туда выводить сразу три текстовых значения? Картинку вместо кнопочки ОК?